# How to create and download file from angular app? Issue with blob

Tags: json, angular, typescript, file, download

I can't download my generated file from app. Code now looks like this:

```
async handleFileTranslateAction(): Promise<void> {
    this.progressSpinerIsVisible = true
    this.originLanguageSelect = await this.languageService.getById(this.selectedOriginLanguage).toPromise()
    this.destinationLanguageSelect = await this.languageService.getById(this.selectedDestinationLanguage).toPromise()
    const result = await this.translateService.getTranslatedJson(
      this.fileInput.getFile(),
      this.originLanguageSelect,
      this.destinationLanguageSelect
    )
    const result2 = JSON.stringify(result)
    console.log(result2)
    const blob = new Blob([result2], { type: 'text/json' });
    console.log(blob)
    this.fileDownloadUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
    // const blob = new Blob([result2], { type: 'text/json' });
    // const url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    // window.open(url);
    const element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('download-final-json-button') as HTMLElement;
    element.click()
    this.progressSpinerIsVisible = false
  }
```

When i consol loging result2, everything showing up correctly, all data is fine, but when i try console log blob and even, when i download a file, i always recieving file contains only this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>TachoTranslations</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
  <body class="mat-typography">
    <tt-root></tt-root>
  <script src="runtime.js" defer></script><script src="polyfills.js" defer></script><script src="styles.js" defer></script><script src="vendor.js" defer></script><script src="main.js" defer></script></body>
</html>
```

The commented section don't works for me. I just want to download json file.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with

```js
   blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'text/json' });
   const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
   window.open(url);
```

edit.

something like this?

```
downloadFromLocal(path) {
    let link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    link.href = `${path}`; //path to the file
    link.download = 'autocertificazione.docx';// name that the file takes
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    link.remove();
  }
```

Comment: Download won't starting

Comment: I realized how to make it working, but it's only opening a raw file, unformatted and ... not downloading it.